# Amazon ec2 ubuntu and issue to connect in a remote smtp

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

Well i'm using amazon ec2 to host files and using a remote smtp to send emails ... i can connect from anywhere in this remote smtp but inside the amazon ec2 when i try to connect it show:

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

very strange, maybe someone could help me? I need to allow some port in firewall ?

thanks.

Comment: Would you show us the applicable code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configserv & Firewall Security Council is ;

After logging in to your WHM panel , click on the left menu configserv Security & Firewall , Firewall Configuration button , click on the resulting page . by SMTP_BLOCK title in front of one (1) i 0 (zero) at the bottom of the page by changing the update ( save, change) click the button . After this process, you must restart CSF Firewall. You can try again to send e-mail after the restart CSF Firewall plug-in.

is not already installed ;

You enterla type the following line at the command prompt after connecting to your server ssh . You can then try to send mail .
service iptables stop